# Round in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I'm trying to figure out away to do this in SQL:

```
100000 % 1000 = 0 

1150000%1000000 = 150000
```

I don't know if there is anything like that in SQL. Or even if there is, I don't know what it is called.

Any idea?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What do you want to achive? Why is it for?

Comment: @Mattia Caputo SQL Server 2014

Comment: Please also take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx

Comment: @labzus the point is to check if the last 3 or 4 or whatever numbers are Zeros or not , if they are Zeros so they matched and otherwise it returned the non matched rest

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1150000 / 1000000 AS result, 1150000 % 1000000 AS reminder;
```

Wich gives : result = 1 & reminder = 150000